# PHP file_exist not working correctly?

Tags: php, file-upload, file-exists

I'm working on a simple file upload functionality in php.

I used [This](http://www.bin-co.com/php/scripts/upload_function/) function to upload three files:

And here is my directory sturcture where i'm storing my files:

```
ROOT-
    -notes-
        -demo-
             -demo_file1.jpg
        -main-
             -main_file1.jpg
        -thumb-
     -manage.php //file which handle uploading code
```

I'm calling upload function like this:

```
$demo_path="notes\demo";
list($demo_file_name,$error)=upload('demo_file',$demo_path,'pdf');
if($error!=""){
    echo 'error-demo'.$error;
    exit;
}
//uploading main file
$main_path="notes\main";
list($file_name,$error)=upload('main_file',$main_path,'pdf');
if($error!=""){
    echo 'error-main'.$error;
    exit;

}

//uploadnig thumbnail
$thumb_path="notes\thumb";
list($thumb_file_name,$error)=upload('file_thumb',$thumb_path,'jpg,gif,jpeg,png');
if($error!=""){
    echo 'error-thumb'.$error;
    exit;

}
```

This code working fine for the demo file and main file,but giving error for thumb saying

> error-thumb Cannot upload the file {filename} : Folder not exist.

Will you please help me to figure out problem?

Thanks in advance.

Note: $_FILES Showing all three files.

Comment: Where are you even using `file_exists()` as your title suggests?

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ there is one at least in link, that OP mentions...

Comment: So isn't the error message very clear that the folder, you are trying to upload this file to, does not exist?

Comment: Could you add the code for the upload function?

Comment: Please provide the specific code, but its pretty clear your path is incorrect according to the error..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the forward slash (`/`) to separate directory names:

```
$thumb_path='notes/thumb';
```

Otherwise `\t` is interpreted as a tab character in double quotes.

Comment: Using single quotes instead of double quotes probably also would work, but slashes is better.

Comment: @Arjan yep, better to combine the two.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, defining a file path directly is considered bad practice.  You should parse the path, create the directory if it doesn't exist, then check whether the directory is readable or not.  For example:

```
function get_the_directory($dir) {
    $upload_dir = trim($dir);
    if(!file_exists($upload_dir)){  // Check if the directory exists
        $new_dir = @mkdir($upload_dir); // Create it if it doesn't 
    }else{
        $new_dir = true;  // Return true if it does
    }
    if ($new_dir) {  // If above is true
        $dir_len = strlen($upload_dir);  // Get dir length
        $last_slash = substr($upload_dir,$dir_len-1,1); // Define trailing slash
        if ($last_slash <> DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) {  // Add trailing slash if one is not present
            $upload_dir = $upload_dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  
        } else {
            $upload_dir = $upload_dir;
        }
        $handle = @opendir($upload_dir);
        if ($handle) { //  Check if dir is readable by the PHP user
            $upload_dir = $upload_dir;
            closedir($handle);
            return $upload_dir;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

> **Note:**the code above is only to illustrate the point and should not be
>   copy-pasted or used in production.

Parsing the path, checking if it exists, creating a new directory if it doesn't, then adding a trailing slash if one doesn't exist should be the approach to completely eliminating server failure, catching errors and returning false.  Development use would entail simply passing an absolute path to your function:

```
$dir = '';
if(!your_dir_function('/path/to/upload/dir/')){
    $dir = 'Sorry, directory could not be created';
}else{
    $dir = your_dir_function('/path/to/upload/dir/');
}

// Write upload logic here

echo $dir;
```

Hope this helps